# How can I use Python's CGIHTTPRequestHandler as a dev server for PHP

Tags: php, python, cgi

I love how to try a Rails app out, I just type `script/server`. I wish there were a way to do something similar from the top level directory of a PHP project.

[This answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/59677/downloading-php-files-from-python-simple-http-server/59695#59695) to the question "Downloading php files from python simple http server" caught my attention.

Any thoughts on how that answer could be adapted to work with a PHP project directory tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to do that, since things such as redirects will be broken. Use something like [WPHP](http://pythonpaste.org/wphp/) instead.

Comment: [How can I use WPHP with Python Paste?](http://serverfault.com/questions/173223/how-can-i-use-wphp-with-python-paste "How can I use WPHP with Python Paste - Server Fault")